# Multiple Buttons doing something

Tags: java, jframe, jpanel

I am still learning how to code in java and I could use a bit of help right now.

This is the current code I wrote. As you can see, it's a simple panel with a bunch of buttons and a slider. I want to make a different console output whenever I hit a different button. So if I hit Back, it's supposed to write Back in the console. If I scroll a bit on the slider, it's supposed to write the new value in the console. Stuff like that. I know it has to be done with actionListener and actionPerformed but after some experimenting I couldn't get it to work.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Gui implements ActionListener {

// Adding all the goods
JFrame frame;
JPanel panel;
JButton endButton;
JButton backButton;
JButton calcButton;
JSlider maxIterations;
JLabel view;

Gui() {

// General
this.frame = new JFrame("Trying my best, I swear");
this.frame.setSize(500, 500);
this.frame.setVisible(true);
this.panel = new JPanel();

// Buttons
this.backButton = new JButton("Back");
this.calcButton = new JButton("Calc");
this.endButton = new JButton("End");
this.panel.add(this.endButton);
this.panel.add(this.calcButton);
this.panel.add(this.backButton);
this.frame.add(this.panel);

// Label
JLabel label1 = new JLabel();
label1.setText("Space Holer");
panel.add(label1);

// Slider
JSlider slider = new JSlider(JSlider.HORIZONTAL, 0, 30, 15);
panel.add(slider);
slider.setMinorTickSpacing(2);
slider.setMajorTickSpacing(5);
slider.setPaintTicks(true);
slider.setPaintLabels(true);

// Make the buttons do something
this.endButton.addActionListener(this);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
System.out.println("End");
}


 public static void main(String[] args) {
  @SuppressWarnings("unused")
  Gui m = new Gui();
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

## You could...

Take advantage of the `actionCommand` property of the button, which is set to the `ActionEvent` when it's created.  If you don't supply an `actionCommand` to the button yourself, it will default to the `text` value, so you could do something like

```
public class ButtonActionHandler implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        switch (e.getActionCommand()) {
            case "Back": 
                System.out.println("Back");
                break;
            case "Calc": 
                System.out.println("Calc");
                break;
            case "End": 
                System.out.println("End");
                break;
        }
    }
    
}
```

This is good if the `ActionListener` is external to the class where the buttons are defined, because you won't have access to the button references.  It's also good, because you could have a number of buttons (including toolbar buttons and menu items) which do the same thing

## You could...

Make use of the `ActionListener`'s `source` property

```
public class ButtonActionHandler implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == backButton) {
            System.out.println("Back");
        } else if (e.getSource() == calcButton) {
            System.out.println("Calc");
        } else if (e.getSource() == endButton) {
            System.out.println("End");
        }
    }

}
```

This is useful if the `ActionListener` in defined as a inner class to the parent class from where the buttons are defined

## You could...

Use an anonymous class registered directly against the button...

```
endButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("End");
    }
});
```

This is good where the button does a single, isolated task

## You could...

Make use of the `Action` API which allows you to define a self contained unit of work, which can be used by buttons to configure themselves completely from it.  This is useful where you have a repeated action which can be executed from different locations of the UI, like a "open file" action contained in the menu bar, tool bar and some wizard.  You can even use it with the key bindings API for extended functionality

See [How to use actions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) for more details

Answer (score 0):

Need to add ActionListener to all buttons,

```
calcButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("calcButton");
            // calculation for slider.
            }
        });

        backButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("backButton");
            }
        });
```

then u get the different console output.

Answer (score 0):

Call `setVisible` on jframe after you placed all components into it.

Add ActionListener to each button. Add ChangeListener to slider as it cannot have ActionListener.

See full code:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSlider;

public class Gui implements ActionListener {

    // Adding all the goods
    JFrame frame;
    JPanel panel;
    JButton endButton;
    JButton backButton;
    JButton calcButton;
    JSlider maxIterations;
    JLabel view;

    Gui() {

        // General
        this.frame = new JFrame("Trying my best, I swear");
        this.frame.setSize(500, 500);
        this.panel = new JPanel();

        // Buttons
        this.backButton = new JButton("Back");
        this.calcButton = new JButton("Calc");
        this.endButton = new JButton("End");
        this.panel.add(this.endButton);
        this.panel.add(this.calcButton);
        this.panel.add(this.backButton);
        this.frame.add(this.panel);

        // Label
        JLabel label1 = new JLabel();
        label1.setText("Space Holer");
        panel.add(label1);

        // Slider
        JSlider slider = new JSlider(JSlider.HORIZONTAL, 0, 30, 15);
        panel.add(slider);
        slider.setMinorTickSpacing(2);
        slider.setMajorTickSpacing(5);
        slider.setPaintTicks(true);
        slider.setPaintLabels(true);

        // Make the buttons do something
        this.endButton.addActionListener(this);
        this.backButton.addActionListener(this);
        this.calcButton.addActionListener(this);
        slider.addChangeListener(e -> {
            Object source = e.getSource();
            if (source instanceof JSlider) {
                int value = ((JSlider) source).getValue();
                System.out.println(value);
            }
        });
        frame.pack();
        this.frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        Object source = ae.getSource();
        if (source instanceof JButton) {
            String text = ((JButton) source).getText();
            System.out.println(text);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        Gui m = new Gui();
    }
}
```